# Remove Facebook apps sidebar in iPad browsers

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, facebook, ipados

Is there any way to remove or hide the sidebar on apps.facebook.com in an iPad browser? I found questions like this one:

https://superuser.com/questions/783581/whats-an-easy-way-to-remove-the-facebook-apps-sidebar?newreg=748cba73733842e997a41a908a030402

but the answers pointed to extensions and greasemonkey scripts, and iPad browsers don't allow those. I am including an image of the sidebar for reference...in a browser on an iPad this sidebar pushes over and covers up a significant part of the app you are in, making the entire page unusable!

EDIT: To add additional information, this sidebar causes this problem in iOS Safari, and also in the iOS versions of both Firefox and Chrome.

[image]

Comment: The best solution is to never open Facebook. Get your life back.

Comment: haha!!  too funny.  From someone  who surfs Ask Different!